# Source editor is removing "onclick" from within my divs

Tags: web-part

I have some HTML within a content web part.

For some reason when I add in the following code to my divs it removes it when I click ok and try to save it.

```
onclick="location.href=http://www.google.com;"
```

It's on a web part page and it doesn't do it on wiki pages I have on the site.

Answer (score 1):

The Content Editor webpart (CEWP) does not allow adding javascript directly in the webpart.

- If this is 2013 you can try the Script Editor webpart as described [here](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/05/20/how-to-use-script-editor-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx).
- In 2010, or if you still want to add the CEWP in 2013, you can use the option to link in the content from a text file as described [here](http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/how-to-use-html-and-javascript-in-content-editor-web-part-in-sharepoint2010/)

Comment: I have a CEWP in another page (its a wiki page) which allows me to insert this line with no issues which is odd.

Comment: It could depend on whether it is a publishing page, wiki page or webpart page. I recall there is some differences in if they strip javascript or not

Comment: The first link for Script Editor Webpart gives 403 Forbidden error